# Cloudflare Server Error 500 - success_fraction - mobile connection to server API error

Tags: ios, django, mobile, cloudflare

After enabling Cloudflare on my Django webapp server, everything seems to work fine.
I notice when I am on WIFI (my mobile app), I can use my server API without problems.
However, when I on mobile data (4G), my mobile app (i'ved also tested directly with API), it will return 500 error.

Here is the following error:

```
<h1>Server Error (500)</h1>
Response headers
 alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400,h3-29=":443"; ma=86400 
 cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC 
 cf-ray: 74968a18ee948986-SIN 
 content-language: en 
 content-type: text/html 
 date: Mon,12 Sep 2022 06:20:49 GMT 
 nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800} 
 report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=XqpSLNdG070p90inA%2Fyz8fGLCaFJd8Ok0Q1LIX1DnZ8f1TB91QxK7C0akJOAxzWikVPGZ1%2BgGZplkOp7fo7Cx8rQDftwF6e%2FE9ZeoRHVrh6d%2BN9XidYUuwBFeAVsp5dmxQt1HrjXGxqY"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800} 
 server: cloudflare 
 vary: Origin,Accept-Language,Cookie 
 x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
```

How can I solve this ? (FYI, I'ved not enabled any WAF firewall rules at all)

Comment: Is there a way you could upload your endpoint code? Also, is there any traceback on your server shell that we could look into?

My guess is that you're checking something from the request headers that triggers a 500 on certain scenarios

Comment: Also, upload your middleware code if you can. Checks on the headers are commonly done on views middleware.

Comment: there is nothing special about this code. It is just a login api code. input username & password, doesnt some internal checks and return success. thats all. What is funny is that it works on WIFI but not on 4G. So, there must be something that cloudflare does.

Comment: There's too little data here to provide a comprehensive answer. What's the full URL involved? When did this issue start? The fact that only 4G has this issue makes me think it's related to your carrier. If you use a VPN with your mobile device, do you see the same issue? What logs does your webserver have for this rayID? If you pay Cloudflare money, then you can contact their Support through the support portal. But as this is a 500 server error, this is your webserver doing something bad, and it's just a matter of figuring out what.

Comment: I use the FREE cloudflare service. It is cloudflare that is causing this. You can argue 500 is server error, but the response is nothing what my server returns. It is a generated response from cloudflare. I have no WAF settings. In fact, recently, I fixed one small issue caused by Cloudflare simply by turning on Web Analytics. That screwed up the API calls. Turning off Web Analytics solved that. Clearly, I need someone to give some direction on this response from Cloudflare. (it works on WIFI, some 4G, but tested on my 4G it doesnt work)